# MPI undefined in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mpi

I was trying to install and run MS-MPI following [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program/) tutorial. I have installed MS-MPI and all my system variables are set correctly, see: [image: vars]

I have set all links in VS[image: lib in linker] [image: lib32] [image: includes]

Having these linked to the project, I would expect MPI to work. In IDE no syntax errors are shown, MPI functions are recognized, just as in next picture. However compiling an c++ source file with MPI functions produces Undeclared identifiers errors. What do I do wrong? [image: recognized]

Here is my code if it matters

```
    /*
    * Transmit a message in a 3-process system.
    */
    #include <mpi.h>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define BUFSIZE 10
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    { int size, rank;
    int slave;
    int buf[BUFSIZE];
    int n, value;
    float rval;
    MPI_Status status;
    /* Initialize MPI  */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    /*
    * Determine size in the world group.
    */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    if (size == 3) {/* Correct number of processes *}
                    /*
                    * Determine my rank in the world group.
                    * The master will be rank 0 and the slaves, rank 1...size-1
                    */

        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

        if (rank == 0) { /* Master */
            buf[0] = 5; buf[1] = 1; buf[2] = 8; buf[3] = 7; buf[4] = 6;
            buf[5] = 5; buf[6] = 4; buf[7] = 2; buf[8] = 3; buf[9] = 1;
            printf("\n Sending the values {5,1,8,7,6,5,4,2,3,1}");
            printf("\n -----------------------------");
            for (slave = 1; slave < size; slave++) {
                printf("\n from master %d to slave %d", rank, slave);
                MPI_Send(buf, 10, MPI_INT, slave, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            printf("\n\n Receiving the results from slaves");
            printf("\n ---------------------------------");
            MPI_Recv(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 11, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("\n Minimum %4d from slave 1", value);
            MPI_Recv(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 21, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("\n Sum     %4d from slave 2", value);
            MPI_Recv(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 12, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("\n Maximum %4d from slave 1", value);
            MPI_Recv(&rval, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 2, 22, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("\n Average %4.2f from slave 2\n", rval);
        }
        else {
            if (rank == 1) { /* minmax slave */
                MPI_Recv(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                value = 100;
                for (n = 0; n<BUFSIZE; n++) {
                    if (value>buf[n]) { value = buf[n]; }
                }
                MPI_Send(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 11, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                value = 0;
                for (n = 0; n<BUFSIZE; n++) {
                    if (value<buf[n]) { value = buf[n]; }
                }
                MPI_Send(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 12, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            else { /* sumave slave */
                MPI_Recv(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                value = 0;
                for (n = 0; n<BUFSIZE; n++) {
                    value = value + buf[n];
                }
                MPI_Send(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 21, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                rval = (float)value / BUFSIZE;
                MPI_Send(&rval, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 22, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return(0);
    }
```

Comment: The #include for stdafx.h must be first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a time I have found where was the bug. Everything is fine with my setting, problem is only with the .cpp extension. Changing it to .c project helped and all works as expected.

If I want to run it as c++, `#include stdafx.h` bust take place before mpi